# Luminaire disconnect

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: ![enter image description here] I saw this a local store and was wondering if I could use this to splice wires together ? it seems like it accepts a couple wires in at one end and then another at the other and then in order to connect the two wires together it snaps them together

Comment: They are used for the same use as wire nuts, more in Europe than here.  Do think the use is limited to junction boxes as wire nuts.  So no having them in the air/in walls by themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These disconnects were made specifically for compliance with NEC 430.130(G) and CEC 30-308(4) which require disconnect plugs like this for fluorescent light ballasts.  At the time this rule was adopted, a lot of conversions were being done from obsolete magnetic T12 ballasts to electronic T8 ballasts, and installers (often not electricians) were getting bit and getting knocked off ladders, especially in 277V circuits which have some serious teeth.  So the geniuses figured "I guess ballast replacements will be a regular thing" right before LED direct-wire came along and mooted the point.

Anyway...

### NEC 110.3(B) You must use equipment according to its labeling and instructions.

Whatever instruction sheet comes with it needs to be followed. But more than that, the labeling specifically identifies it as a **luminaire** disconnect. Luminaire is NEC-speak for light fixture.  Using them *off-label* will be problematic.  Probably fine for something like a "fan" in a "light and fan" setup. But for a motor load, you could be red-flagged on that.

Note also the current rating. They [are rated for](https://buy.wesco.com/static/catalog/products/images/PDF/873-902.pdf) 20A pass-through on the double-port side, since that is intended to daisy-chain fixtures. However, on the luminaire side it has a 6 amp max, and only permits 18 AWG *solid* wire, which is typical inside fluorescent fixtures but unusual elsewhere.

Further, it is only rated for being used inside the internal wiring of a fixture, not "out in the open" as a general-use connector. For that use NEMA 1-15 or 5-15.

So no, you cannot use this as a general-purpose disconnect.  In particular it is not rated for a connection to be buried behind wall materials. Those still need junction boxes.